# Potential leak of an object allocated on line 23 and stored into "info"

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks

```
- (IBaction)switchview6:(id)sender {
    information *info = [[Information alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:info animated:YES]; }
```

And then I get this error:

```
Potential leak of an object allocated on line 23 and stored into "info"
```

Please my friends how do I fix this? Can you type me the exact line when it is correct?
I read a lot of topics by I couldn't understand.

Comment: You heard of [Memory Management in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) ? And don't ask us to write code for you. This is not Q&A forum.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, after you create a view controller just to add it present it modally, you need to release the view controller.

Try adding the line:

```
[info release];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer you were right.Now i am facing another error when i choose archive. Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011). What is this and how do i solve it?

Comment: @KyriakosStavrakidis That's a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are allocating the memory and not releasing it. You need to read the memory rules and understand them, otherwise your code will leak or crash or both.

CHeck out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

and search here for memory management and ou will find many such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Enable ARC for your project so that you don't have to deal with memory management stuff. If this is an already created project you can migrate into arc as well.

Either way follow this link to Understand about memory management and to learn how to convert your project into arc

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1